# How to optimize settings (brightness, contrast) on external monitors for proper color calibration in macOS for work in low lighting conditions?

Tags: display, color

I have several monitors attached to a Mac Pro and unfortunately I have some issues with variations of their brightness and contrast due to their being largely different model monitors. I've tried the Apple calibration tool before (advanced option) that tells you to crank up your contrast all the way and then tweak the brightness from there to get the box looking right, but this no longer seems to look right on Catalina.

I've shifted gears to a ColorMunki Display, but since their software pretty much doesn't work well (or even at all with the number of monitors I have), I'm left with [DisplayCAL](https://displaycal.net/).

DisplayCAL is really quite awesome, but I keep having troubles with my black and white levels leaving me with slightly grey of each.

This brings me back to my original question: *How does one figure out what the best settings for brightness, contrast, etc. would be for monitors before even jumping into the real calibration phase?*

I've read that one solid starting point is getting a light meter on your iPhone / iPad and trying to get the brightness levels all roughly the same.  I did actually do this, and it was helpful for my eyes, but didn't resolve the grey-blacks and grey-whites issue.

**This problem is exacerbated for me by working in a dark room / studio 90% of the time and thus I need to work with lower lighting and brightness settings.**

Comment: What doesn't work with X-Rite's own software? I've tried theirs & DisplayCAL & definitely get better results with X-Rite. btw, you probably want to set your screens to calibrate at 100 cd/m² or even possibly as low as 80 if it's really dark, compared to the standard 120 cd/m², but that is going to reduce your gamut, as black levels will not fall significantly.

Comment: First, their i1Studio crashes and even spits out an error about not supporting 6 monitors. Second, I've been using ~240 lux as a baseline (not sure what that equates to for cd/m² since your unit doesn't have *sr in it - perhaps it's the same. Is there a way to determine optimal light levels based on ambient lighting? Ie, X ambient lux means monitors' lux levels should be at Y? So far I'm just seeing "recommended" levels documentation vs actual suggested calculations based on real ambient levels.

Comment: 1. Why don't you unplug a couple while you're doing the setup, it's not as though you can really work whilst one screen is flipping through its 420-page colour-chart. 2. You don't measure a screen's brightness in lux, lux is dependant on distance from source, cd/m² isn't, the meter will measure in cd/m² for you. 3. iDisplay [I used to own an older colormunki not the new one, so idk if that also can] can measure & compensate for ambient light, but only if you use X-Rite software.